# Trying to produce faded margins

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to produce a faded gradient for the left and right margins on my website, but the only way I can think to go about it is found on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/btzr1vox/

```
body {
   background-color: #fafafa;
}
 
.box-1 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(250, 250, 250) 0%, rgb(0, 0, 0, 1) 15%);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}

.box-2 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(0, 0, 0) 85%, rgb(250, 250, 250, 1) 100%);
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.row {
  max-width: 114rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col-1-of-2 {
    width: calc((100% - #{6rem}) / 2);
}

.color {
  color: white;
}

.column-1 {
  margin-right: 3rem;
}

.column-2 {
  margin-left: 3rem;
}
```

It works, but it divides the the page into to columns, which I don't want, as I would have to repeat the process for each section of the website. This seems like a hassle, especially if I want to change the width of the columns, such as a block that only takes up 1/3 of the page, and the other 2/3, and so on.

Comment: I've encountered the same issue. My solution was to remove the outline completely and then play around with box shadow. Google chrome has some really useful tools to go along with that. You can start by inspecting the div and adding box-shadow.

Comment: Here, take a look:
https://jsfiddle.net/ud2gyjhc/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest separating the white gradient from the elements that hold your text, so they're not dependent on each other. Even easier: if you create two elements and apply the `position: absolute;` property on them, you can re-use them wherever you want: on top of the whole background, or per section.

If you run into problems with text covering the gradient, you can of course give the element that holds your text a `padding` equal to the `width` of the gradients, so they never touch them.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #36393f;
}

.gradient-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%
  );
}

.gradient-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to left,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-left"></div>
<div class="gradient-right"></div>
```

Comment: I like this. Looks like it can easily be used without filling the page with text a hassle. Thanks.